# Decrease bootstrap datepicker end date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker for one on my project and set endDate like this

```
$('#daterange').data('daterangepicker').setEndDate('2017/03/12');
```

EndDate is somthign that i get from database, only problem is that on datepicker i have to set endDate but decrease one date, it measn if i have something from server like this

**2017/03/12**

I need to bind datepicker like this

```
$('#daterange').data('daterangepicker').setEndDate('2017/03/11');
```

is it possible to do that in frontend or i must go to server to correct, any simple solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com) 
`moment("your date", "YYYY/MM/DD").subtract(1, 'days').format('YYYY/MM/DD');`

Comment: is you already load the momentjs? <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>

Comment: upss sorry, moment("your date", "YYYY/MM/DD").subtract(1, 'days');

Comment: updated. If you wanna get the string, just add .format('YYYY/MM/DD').

Comment: I got this Fri Jul 20 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148395/discussion-between-jefferson-setiawan-and-miomir-dancevic).

Answer (score 0):

What i will do:

`1. get date from database ( 2017/03712)
2. change it to datetime format
3. decrease one day
4. setEndDate with correct format`